# C# Setting Variable to outcome of if statement

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework

I am trying to write a foreach loop to loop through an array of user license numbers and set a variable to the license number where the license number state matches the listing state, else set the ln to be the first one in the array.  My code is here

```
var realEstateAgent = await realEstateAgentRepository.GetRealEstateAgentAsync(request.RealEstateAgentGuid);

            var listing = await repository.GetListingAsync(new GetListingRequest { Guid = request.ListingGuid });

            string realEstateAgentlicenseNumber = null;

            Array.ForEach(realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers, licensNumber  =>
            {
                if (licenseNumber.State == listing.Listing.State)
                {
                    realEstateAgentlicenseNumber = licenseNumber.License;
                }
                else
                {
                    realEstateAgentlicenseNumber = realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers[0].LicenseNumber.License;
                }
            });
```

I am struggling to i understand and resolve the error I am seeing here

```
The type arguments for method 'Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: You need too specify the type, just as it says. The type is specified between in this form `<T>`. So if LicenseNumbers is `int[]`, you want to write `Array.ForEach<int>`

Answer (score 0):

The error just means that the compiler cannot infer the type for `T` of the `ForEach` method you are calling.

Try `Array.ForEach<NameOfTheTypeOfTheItem>(...)`

The type would be whatever your type of items in `realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers
```

this should be an array make sure it`s an array, if its a list try to call .ToArray()

realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers.ToArray()

Comment: I see, I will remember that for next time I come across this,  thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

licenseNumber in this line is misspelled:

```
Array.ForEach(realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers, licensNumber  =>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to see if this code can be simplified. I am not sure if the below would work, but could be worth a try!

If realEstateAgent.LisenceNumber is of type IEnumerable, then we can do something like this:

```
var realEstateAgentlicenseNumber = realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers
                                  .Where(x => x.State == listing.Listing.State)
                                  .Select(x => x.License)
```

If we don't find a match, the realEstateAgentlicenseNumber would be null or empty. and in that case, we can assign the first value as follows:

```
var realEstateAgentlicenseNumber = realEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers.First()
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we ended up doing something similar, I was definitely making it more complicated than it had to be with my first approach

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you got a solution :)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so here is what we ended up doing, worked in our case

```
    RealEstateAgentLicenseNumber =
                        listingResponse.RealEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers.FirstOrDefault(f => f.State == listingResponse.Listing.State)?.License ??
                        listingResponse.RealEstateAgent.LicenseNumbers.FirstOrDefault()?.License ??
                        string.Empty,
```